# How do I serialize/deserialize an HTML table in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I am trying to write a class to serialize/deserialize something as simple as:

```
<table border="1">
 <tr>
 <td>row 1, cell 1</td>
 <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
 <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

I have gotten to the point of (see below) but just can't get it to generate the table xml correctly:

```
Imports System.Xml.Serialization

<XmlRoot("TABLE")>
Public Class HTMLTable

    <XmlArray("")>
    <XmlArrayItem(GetType(HTMLTableRow), elementName:="TR")>
    Public Property Rows As New List(Of HTMLTableRow)

    <XmlType("TR")>
    Public Class HTMLTableRow

        <XmlArray("TD")>
        Public Property Cells As New List(Of HTMLTableCell)
    End Class

    <XmlType("TD")>
    Public Class HTMLTableCell

        <XmlText()>
        Public Property Value As String
    End Class
   End Class
```

With a test like:

```
  <Test()>
    Public Sub SerializeTest()
        Dim tbl As New HTMLTable
        Dim row As New HTMLTable.HTMLTableRow
        Dim cell As New HTMLTable.HTMLTableCell
        row.Cells.Add(cell)
        tbl.Rows.Add(row)
        Debug.Print(XMLProcessor.Serialize(tbl))
    End Sub
```

I just can't get it to serialize to this thing. I tried to generate the class using xsd but that produced a lot of garbage code and I really would like to maintain this by hand as it is easier than the monstrosity that xsd produced which didn't work anyway. What am I doing wrong above?

Comment: Before answering, are you doing this in an attempt to use the result in some sort of real-world application, or are you just trying to learn about serialization?

Comment: In an in-house shop so people stop writing HTML code to generate a table in their VB.NET code. Why would that impact your answer?

Comment: Because there are classes built in for doing that.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmltextwriter.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing:

```
<XmlArray("")>
<XmlArrayItem(GetType(HTMLTableRow), elementName:="TR")>
Public Property Rows As New List(Of HTMLTableRow)
```

into:

```
<XmlElement("TR")>
Public Property Rows As New List(Of HTMLTableRow)
```

, and change:

```
<XmlArray("TD")>
Public Property Cells As New List(Of HTMLTableCell)
```

into:

```
<XmlElement("TD")>
Public Property Cells As New List(Of HTMLTableCell)
```

That is how I would set up the attributes when using `XmlSerializer` for the same task.

I would also move the `HTMLTableRow` and `HTMLTableCell` classes out of the `HTMLTable` class.

On another note, your test method isn't really a test method, since it doesn't do any `Assert` and it doesn't throw an exception when the result doesn't meet your requirements!

Comment: You da man!!! Just what I needed. This test wasn't really a test method... It was my attempt to just get the serialize to work the way I want to see it. I was going to re-write it with Assert once I had it...

Comment: You're doing the testing backwards... :)

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want to do here is use one of the built-in classes for generating HTML, rather than attempting to serialize an object model.

Check out [HtmlTextWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmltextwriter.aspx), for instance, or if you want fuller functionality, [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Too bad we're stil on .NET 2.0

Comment: HTML Agility pack is based on 2.0- from the web site: "The version posted here on CodePlex is for the .NET Framework 2.0"

Comment: And `HtmlTextWriter` exists in 1.0.

Answer (score -2):

I don't see the Serializable() attribute declared at the class level.. 
Best regards